# Hardening SSL/TLS on Azure Cloud Service for A+ on Qualys SSL Labs?

Tags: tls, webserver, hardening, iis, azure

We're using [this powershell script](https://gist.github.com/sidshetye/29d6d48dfa0c2f5488a4) as our Azure Cloud Service (PaaS) startup script and we're at an A- on the [Qualys SSL Labs test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest)

Specifically we're losing points for the following reasons:

```
Forward Secrecy : With some browsers (more info)
Downgrade attack prevention : No, TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV not supported (more info)
```

We'd like to set it up for an A+ on that one (and improve other aspects not covered in that test). How can we do so?

Answer (score 4):

First, for an analysis of TLS version and cipher suite selection, see [my answer to Now that it is 2015, what SSL/TLS cipher suites should be used in a high security HTTPS environment?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/77018/39623)

- The summary is: TLS_DHE_* and TLS_ECDHE_* support PFS, but AVOID *DSS*, *RC4*, and so on.
- The reason you're getting points off for not having FS with some browsers is the TLS_RSA_* cipher suites; take them out of your startup script.

Then, for an additional technical "how do I do this on Azure", please read [How do I configure Perfect Forward Secrecy in Windows Azure (OS, or Websites)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20450631/1967612)

- The summary is: Run an [Azure startup task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/hh180155.aspx) like the one in this [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NWebsec.AzureStartupTasks/) in this [Codeplex project](https://nwebsec.codeplex.com), and make sure to disable SSLv3 entirely.

  - It sounds like your startup script is already doing a lot of this, which is great!

As far as TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV goes, your best bet is to get all your friends to give your feedback to Microsoft regarding [the TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV Connect entry](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1002874/internet-explorer-should-send-tls-fallback-scsv)

Comment: FYI the TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV issue you linked to in Connect is for I.E., but to get an A+ on the SSLLabs test it would need to be implemented in IIS instead.