# Disable support for static key cipher suites

Tags: tls, windows, cipher-selection, windows-7

I have a requirement to disable in the windows 7 computers of the company the support for static key cipher suites.

I have searched and found that this registry key, holds the allowed cipher suites, in a value called Functions.

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Cryptography\Configuration\SSL\00010002
```

I have searched about how to identify the static suites in order to remove them from the list. but I haven't found anything.

My question is what I need to search in the ciphers string, to remove the support for static keys.

> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA25,.....

Comment: Static cipher suites are suites that do not provide [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy). Maybe it is easier to enable [cipher suites that are recommended](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76993/now-that-it-is-2015-what-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-should-be-used-in-a-high-securit) instead of disabling bad ones.

Answer (score 1):

As stated earlier by Sjoerd '**Static cipher suites** are suites that do NOT provide **forward secrecy**'. So our objective is to limit ciphers suites to those which do have forward secrecy feature.

**Forward Secrecy** is provided by the ephemeral aspect of **DHE** (Diffie-Hellman Ephemeral) and **ECDHE** (Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman Ephemeral) ciphers.
**Ephemeral** DH uses a distinct key for each exchange vs. one key for entire session used with fixed DH.

The perfect forward secrecy offered by DHE comes at a price: more computation. The ECDHE variants uses elliptic curve cryptography to reduce this computational cost.

The list provided by Roger Martínez Hernández above includes only those **cipher suites that have DHE or ECDHE in them**. So the list is good. An easy way to implement this is to use **IIS Crypto 3.0** and select or check only these ciphers from the "Cipher Suites" section.

Comment: Your answer is useful content, @JayKulsh. But I am not sure, if it is an answer to the question (on the top). Are you sure that you wanted to react that question? It is a requirement here.

Comment: It is answer to the original question. It was already stated by Sjoerd that "Static cipher suites are suites that do not provide forward secrecy. " Let me add this line to my answer to make this obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you so far:

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P384
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384_P384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256_P256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256_P384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P384
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

If you are going to introduce them in a line separe it by commas (,) there should not be spaces

Comment: Welcome on the site! How did you get the list? How could the OP disable exactly these? I would suggest to give these details, it would hugely improve your answer.