# Guidelines for TLS cipher suites?

Tags: tls, penetration-test, cipher-selection

Other than OWASP, are there any other guidelines for recommended TLS/SSL versions as well as their specific cipher suites?

Answer (score 5):

- Mozilla: https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/
- SSL Labs: https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/SSL-and-TLS-Deployment-Best-Practices
- Cipherli.St: https://cipherli.st/
- OWASP: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SSL_Best_Practices

  - And here: especially the *"Related articles"* section at the bottom: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Transport_Layer_Protection_Cheat_Sheet
- Similar question: [Now that it is 2015, what SSL/TLS cipher suites should be used in a high security HTTPS environment?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76993/now-that-it-is-2015-what-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-should-be-used-in-a-high-securit)